# Horizontally Scaling Parse Server?

Tags: parse-server

Are separate instances of Parse Server independent? IOW, do they coordinate through the MongoDB backend? I suspect so. If so, then I can run multiple systems behind a load balancer and synthesize something with a bit better availability. I can also spin up my web apps and give them their own private Parse Server to query the database.

Can anyone confirm or deny whether a Parse Server is horizontally scalable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is horizontally scalable, we currently run 7-10 instances depending on the load without any issue. you mongodb server should be big enough to accept all those connections

Comment: Do you know if this is also true of live queries? Are these coordinated through the data source or handled within the application server (causing issues with horizontal scaling)?

Comment: You’ll need redis or something like that to coordinate messaging across live queries

Comment: Is this supported by Parse Server or would we have to design our own solution for this? Standing up Redis isn't hard, but wiring things up properly with Parse could be.

Comment: This should be supported out of the box

Answer (score 0):

One thing to think about as well is using a clustering, throng, pm2 to take advantage if you have more cores for the server your using.

Node.js only runs on one core so if you have beefy servers with multiple cores you should also spawn more parse instances.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your insights. As a mobile developer who chose Parse to specifically avoid knowing these details, it is very nice to know there is a vibrant community of both Node and Parse Server developers willing to help. As a result of M. Vilmart's answer above, I am using NodeChef to host my Parse Servers. I suspect they know all about those load balancing tools.